# Jquery javascript best practise when adding removing css classes to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wonder what the best practise is when adding and removing css classes to a element.

Eg:

```
$('.item').addClass('hidden');
```

This works every time, even if the class `.item` already has a class hidden attached to it, it doesnt get the class added multiple times.

However I could do this as well:

```
if ($('.item').hasClass('hidden') == false) {
   $('.item').addClass('hidden');
}
```

But I dont see any reason I need to, but are there any pros and cons in the two examples?

Comment: Well it's a questionable practice to make explicit comparisons for boolean values (testing for `== false` is what I mean) but you're right, `.addClass()` will check anyway.

Comment: if the class is already there it wont add another one of the same name. Test it by trying to add it multiple times with .addClass

Comment: I guess the method addClass require more time to process than the hasClass. So if hasClass return false it saves time because will not execute the next line.

Comment: FYI. I think you are suppose to use the `hidden` attribute instead of classes.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp

Comment: Have you tried this - http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addClass` already starts off by checking whether the element already has the class, so your check before calling is duplicating something that it already does.

There's a little extra checking first to see if the argument is a function rather than a string. But the time this takes should generally be negligible.